# Apache not starting while installing RT5: DATABASE access issue

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql

Apache is not starting.

```
(rt5venv) root@devrt5:/etc/apache2/sites-available# systemctl start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Try 1:**

```
(rt5venv) root@devrt5:/etc/apache2/sites-available# systemctl status apache2
```

Or with `journalctl -xe`:

```
Dec 20 17:44:44 devrt5 apachectl[19768]: connectivity problem.
Dec 20 17:44:44 devrt5 apachectl[19768]: The error RT got back when trying to connect to your database
Dec 20 17:44:44 devrt5 apachectl[19768]: Connect Failed Access denied for user 'rt_user'@'localhost'
Dec 20 17:44:44 devrt5 apachectl[19768]:  at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT.pm line 222.
Dec 20 17:44:44 devrt5 RT[19771]: [19771] DBI 
connect('dbname=rt5;host=localhost','rt_user',...)
Dec 20 17:44:45 devrt5 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 20 17:44:45 devrt5 sudo[19765]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 20 17:44:45 devrt5 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 20 17:44:45 devrt5 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
```

**More tries:**

```
(rt5venv) root@devrt5:/tmp/rt-5.0.2# /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-server &
[2] 21336
[1]   Exit 2                  /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-server
(rt5venv) root@devrt5:/tmp/rt-5.0.2# 
RT couldn't connect to the database where tickets are stored.
If this is a new installation of RT, you should visit the URL below
to configure RT and initialize your database.

If this is an existing RT installation, this may indicate a database
connectivity problem.
```

The error RT got back when trying to connect to your database was:

```
Connect Failed Access denied for user 'rt_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT.pm line 222.
```

I have also done the following:

1. Granted all privileges on `rt5.*` to `rt_user@localhost` with `grant` option.
2. Set up the password as well as `rt_user` for the DB in `rt_siteconfig.pm`.

I can get into MySQL using `mysql -u root -p` and it works perfectly fine.

I am happy to provide further details on file info if needed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure which MySQL user account you're using for the webite. `rt_user` or `root`. As @guiverc has stated, `root` cannot be used by systems (unless run as `sudo`). Does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` contain any actionable information to explain the problem?

Comment: Here is more detail on the system: Distributor ID:Ubuntu; Description:Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS; Release:18.04; Codename:bionic

I am using rt_user as my SQL user. Following is the information I found in the error.log:

 Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

RT couldn't connect to the database where tickets are stored.
If this is an existing RT installation, this may indicate a database
connectivity problem.

The error RT got trying to connect to your database was:

Connect Failed Access denied for user 'rt_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT.pm line 222.